# CSPADE method in R throws ERROR: no slot of name "transactionInfo" for this object of class "transactions"

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis

I get error in R when running the following method for CSPADE algorithm (finding association rules in transactions):

```
x <- read_baskets(con = system.file("misc", "zaki.txt", package = "arulesSequences"), info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))

s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.4), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
parameter specification:
support : 0.4
maxsize :  10
maxlen  :  10

algorithmic control:
bfstype  : FALSE
verbose  :  TRUE
summary  : FALSE
tidLists : FALSE

preprocessing ...
Error in typeof(x) : 
  no slot of name "transactionInfo" for this object of class "transactions"
```

"x" is a transaction object and it gets successfully created but for some reason the cspade method does not work (even on its classic data set which is provided in its documentation)

Comment: This question is not clear as written. You should include a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Not sure which part is not clear but let me elaborate a bit. The text file "zaki.txt" is part of the arulesSequences package so everyone who has installed that package, does have that data set. The first line of the code executes and creates a transaction object "x". the second line (cspade) gives that error, although I just copy-pasted the same code snippet from the cspade doc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but for next readers, I think this bug appeared after an upgrade of the package.

Just add :

```
attributes(x)$transactionInfo <- x@itemsetInfo
```

after creating x with read_baskets()

Comment: I ran into the same error and this does solve the problem!